# HP MicroServer N54L - HP logo light not lit

Tags: hpe

I bought an HP MicroServer N54L recently, and a few days ago, upgraded the RAM to 8GB from 4GB.

When I booted it up again, the HP health LED lit up red briefly, then turned off again. I noted that the power LED was on, fans were spinning, but the HP health LED was not lit, but the NIC was active, and the disks (MiniSAS) briefly. There is no VGA output either.

I'm a bit stuck. I've also tried clearing the CMOS, with little success.

If I haven't given enough information on this question, please do let me know, and I'll endeavour to provide it. Additionally, if I've made any mistakes or anything, please let me know as well - I will try to fix them!

Any ideas? I hope the motherboard isn't fried.

Comment: Have you tried removing the RAM and reverting to original, then seeing if it powers on?

Comment: Have you tried putting the 4GB RAM back in? Is the 8GB RAM supported?

Comment: I have put the original 4GB RAM back in, and booted it up, with the same behaviour.

Comment: Did that box work first when you bought it? Have you made sure you reconnected everything correctly after upgrading?

Comment: @Zac67 Yep, all working when I bought it. It's only since I upgraded RAM. Everything's connected, and even when MiniSAS is disconnected, it still doesn't output anything. Very bizarre...